# Make a Cell Blink/Flash in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I tried the following formula to make a specific cell to Blink until a value is added:

```
function blinkCell() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1"); // Replace "A1" with the desired cell reference
  var originalColor = cell.getBackground();

  setInterval(function() {
    var currentColor = cell.getBackground();
    if (currentColor == originalColor) {
      cell.setBackground("red"); // Replace "red" with the desired blinking color
    } else {
  cell.setBackground(originalColor);
}
  }, 1000); // Adjust the interval (in milliseconds) to control the blinking speed
}
```

But I am getting an error:
ReferenceError: setInterval is not defined
blinkCell   @ BLINK.gs:6

I am sharing the Google Sheet sample file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NhMP812BJRazPk9te_wTstoECCMW3TJpd7-8I7rkElI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: setInterval only works on the browser not the Google Server so you would have to run that from a dialog or webapp as pure javascript and access the server with a google.script.run

Comment: @Cooper Do you have an alternative?

Comment: This is not clear: "to Blink until a value is added". Which cell do you want to add the value to? What value should stop blinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account the comments of the author of the post, I adjusted the original code.
I should note that it is not a good idea to not limit the blinking time. This means that if the user does not enter anything into the cell, the script will continue to run until it is stopped by the Google server due to exceeding the limit (6 minutes). It is better to provide a time limit in the script, for example, using a loop.

Try the following code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B3");
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (range.getValue() === "") {
      range.setBackground("red");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      range.setBackground("white");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(1000)
    }
  }
}
```

Here the blinking will continue for some time on the edited sheet until some value appears in cell B3.

Note. Since cells B3 and C3 are combined, it is enough to write B3 in the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
It works but only when the cell has content inside.
I want it to flash even when it's empty, for those using the file, to remind them to fill in that cell.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly, you want the cell to blink until a value is entered into it?

Comment: Yes exactly and not in one cell but in 2 or 4 simultaneously.
Please read the reply I gave to @Logan just now

Comment: It's not a good idea to not limit the blinking time. This means that if the user does not enter anything into the cell, the script will continue to run until it is stopped by the Google server due to exceeding the limit (6 minutes). It is better to provide a time limit in the script, for example, using a loop.

Comment: Boris thank you so much for your reply. I've got your point about time and you are right!
It is working just fine! How to make it loop let's say for 1 minute 5 times?
Can it flash in 3 or more different cells simultaneously in the same TAB if I want?
Also please check my response I wrote below on how to make it run in all TABS, since my original Google Sheets file has 30 TABs, one for each day of the month

Comment: How to make it run in all TABS, in my original Google Sheets file except the 3 first TABs named "START", "HELP", "MASTER"

Comment: I'm glad. If my answer answers your question originally asked in the post, you can accept it.
It is better to ask other questions in a new post.

Comment: Boris because I cannot open a new post for that can you please assist me instead of range.setBackground("white") to be with the (originalColor)?

Comment: function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B3");  
  var originalColor = range.getBackground();
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (range.getValue() === "") {
      range.setBackground("red");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      range.setBackground(originalColor);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(1000)
    }
  }
}

Comment: Thank you for your fast response it is working fine.
May I please ask you one more thing? How do you select different cells?
I tried that:

  var range = sheet.getRange("C4");
  var range = sheet.getRange("C15");

but, it is not working it blinks only the C15

Comment: Also I tried 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList["C4", "C8"];
  sheet.setActiveRangeList(rangeList);

Still not working

Comment: parentheses: 

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(['A:A', 'C:C']);
rangeList.setBackground('red');

Comment: Boris I used your modifications with the following script:
function onEdit2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(["C5", "C8"]);
  var originalColor = range.getBackground(); //It keeps the original color
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (range.getValue() === "") {
      rangeList.setBackground("red");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      range.setBackground(originalColor); //It keeps the original color
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(1000)

It is not working. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: In order for a trigger to fire automatically, it must be called strictly onEdit(), but not onEdit2().

Comment: Because I had the timestamp script  with onEdit and when I added the blink script  of yours with onEdit, the timestamp function was not working so I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/55262195/22804395

function onEdit(e){
  onEdit1(e);
  onEdit2(e);
}
after everything was working just fine timeStamp and blink.
Check my Google sheet and you will understand better.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var originalColor = cell.getBackground()
  var i = 0;
  do {
    Utilities.sleep(300);
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      cell.setBackground("RED");
    } else {
      cell.setBackground(originalColor);
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    i++;
    if (cell.getValue() != "") {
      cell.setBackground(originalColor);
      break;
    }
  } while (true);
}``
```

#### Result:

[image]

---

Just change the value of the cell to which cell you want to blink. Also take note that it will only start blinking once the function is ran and it will not stop running until there is value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
It's pretty much exactly what I want.
It works but with some limitations for the file I'm working with and the job I need it for.

The Google Sheet that I share with my colleagues is a file that is opened daily by office managers.
Starting in the morning every day they open a specific Excel sheet that in the first initial tab has only one button.
This button once pressed runs a code that creates a new TAB that is a copy of a "MASTER TAB" that has all the cells with the daily tasks they have to complete every day.

Comment: The code that runs to create the duplicate is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77383269/22804395 of Mr. @TANAIKE 

In this case, the code doesn't work unless I go to the script window with the code and press the run button for the active TAB.

Can it be made to run automatically for every new TAB created?

Can it flash in 3 or more different cells simultaneously in the same TAB if I want?

Thank you again for your help.